# I am using add_serial_number VbA code but is getting overflow error

Tags: excel, vba

Below my code is given.

I have only 20K rows.
I am using long data type but don't know why i am getting run time error.

```
Option Explicit

Sub add_serial_num()
    
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long
    
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lr
        
        If Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
            Cells(i, "A").Value = i - 1
            
        End If
                    
    Next i
            
End Sub
```

Getting run time error of overflow.
I have used long data type. But i don't know why i am getting this error.
I have only 20K rows.
I am using long data type but don't know why i am getting run time error.

Comment: On what line do you get the overflow?

Comment: Try adding in some errorr handling to catch the overflow error.  That way can place  a breakpoint when the overflow error occurs and inspect the various variables causing it.  Overflow errors occur when attempting to store a value outside of its range of allowable values. See: [data-type-summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) Possible solutions use eg LongLong type or catch the error etc. VBA Err.Number for OVERFLOW = 6 if checking specifically for that.

Comment: I don't see anything that could cause the error. Do you have by any chance any Trigger code when the worksheet is changed?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if one of the cells in column B has a format applied to it, but the value doesn't match the format. For example if a cell is formatted as date, but the value is 1,000,000,000.

Check the format and value of whatever row the code stops on.

Another option is to use `.Value2` instead of `.Value`, this will ignore the formatting.

Comment: Probably the issue, with some error handling they should be able to identify the cell location and/or how to treat invalid data i.e. outside the range of a Long value if expecting values only within the range of a Long type. Or use a type that holds a greater range of values.  Other issues what if a cells value is not a numeric value?

Comment: That doesn't apply here, he is not assigning the value of any cell to the long variable. He is only assigning the row number.

Comment: "For example if a cell is formatted as date, but the value is 1,000,000,000" - this does not cause a run-time Overflow error....

Comment: It does when you try to access `.Value`. To reproduce the error: enter 1,000,000,000 in A1, format as date, and in the immediate window use `?range("a1").Value` to produce the error. Then use `?range("a1").Value2` to produce no error. And change the format back to general, and `?range("a1").Value` will produce no error.